# Firefox CSS spacing issues cross-os

Tags: css, firefox

I'm having an issue with Firefox. It displays differently in Windows than on OSX. It looks to be a font spacing issue, or font size, but I can't figure it out. Both use the exact same properties.

Top Window: Mac OSX, Bottom: WinXP

[image: CSS Mac vs Windows]

Here's the basic HTML/Computed Style:[image]
[image]

Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: Would help if you post the HTML/CSS to show this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hoping to build the best cross-browser experience, a few CSS tweaks will make for a more forgiving layout and lessen any font rendering differences.

For example, to improve your current markup you should:

- Float or absolutely position `<div class="topNav">` to the top, right of its parent element
- Right align all the text within `topNav`

This will ensure that your top navigation will always grow to the left, and not go beyond the page to the right (as pictured in the bottom Windows XP/Firefox screenshot).

After this change, the font differences will be lessened, since the layout can grown or expand gracefully while changes the `cartNav` won't break the layout.

While you're making these changes, you might consider combining the sub-nav icons into a [CSS Sprite](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#opt_sprites).

As Web Developers, we're accustomed to browser testing and rendering inconsistencies, but consider that it's highly unlikely anyone except yourself *(perhaps of course a fellow developer, or client)* would ever compare the way the site renders between browsers or operating systems.

Comment: I never thought Firefox could be such a difference between OSs (especially when IE looks fine). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely seeing a delta because of the font chosen.  There are only a handful of fonts that are common across Windows & Mac, some of which (Lucida Sans/Lucida Sans Unicode) which contain different kerning across those platforms.

It would be very helpful to see the CSS font information for the elements in question.

The solutions (assuming it is the kerning issue mentioned above):

1. Choose a font that kerns better on both platforms.  Arial may work well in this case.
2. Pick a narrower font and ensure that it works on both platforms.
3. Make sure the design can accomodate extra width. I think you'll find that you have a problem in Windows if you have 10 items in your cart or go above $100.

You can use cufon for this, but I'm not a huge fan of it because of the licensing and printability issues.  You can license a font pretty cheaply from somebody like MyFonts.

Comment: Apparently my rep is too low to comment properly, but I see that somebody has suggested a CSS letter-spacing hack.  Letter-spacing uses 1px boundaries, which isn't nearly fine enough for your purposes.  You'll wind up with a lot of headache trying to explore that path.

Comment: The font should be Verdana on both OSs. I doubt that would make that much of difference between OSs would it?

Comment: Yes, Verdana has a pretty significant shift between OS's.  Note that this is an OS thing, not a browser thing.

You can always use a multi-rendering solution like Adobe's BrowserLab to view the differences:
https://browserlab.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

font kerning differences between the OS's looks like.
It's VERY hackish, but if you can't use a font that's more consistent between versions, you can always hack the kerning... http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp